# Adding a DATETIME column via a migration? Should I use macros?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

In Laravel 4 there's a `dateTime()` function that helps in creating these columns. But in `Schema\Table` in Laravel 3, I only see a `date()` function, which is:

```php
public function date($name)
{
    return $this->column(__FUNCTION__, compact('name'));
}
```

Looks like it just creates a DATE column. However, I also see that there's this magic function:

```php
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (isset(static::$macros[$method]))
    {
        array_unshift($parameters, $this);
        return call_user_func_array(static::$macros[$method], $parameters);
    }

    throw new \Exception("Method [$method] does not exist.");
}
```

Is there a way to create a DATETIME column using this function? How do I go about it? Could not find this info in the documentation.

Comment: Isn't $table->timestamp('column') what you're looking for? Check http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema.

Comment: No, not a timestamp, I need a DATETIME, but the final answer is a 'doh' moment though. I'll answer my own question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:\

Turns out Macros is a [recently added](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1853) (very cool) feature, but this wouldn't have helped me. In order to add a new column, one would actually have to modify the `Schema\Table` class, and then add a new method in the [MySQL grammars](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/cffded660c2c5158bc1c7ae404b6b9ab1eaee460/laravel/database/schema/grammars/mysql.php) file for table columns. Macros only helps with doing multiple things with the existing table methods at once.

Funnily enough, once I went there, it actually turns out that Laravel indeed [already makes](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/cffded660c2c5158bc1c7ae404b6b9ab1eaee460/laravel/database/schema/grammars/mysql.php#L385) `DATETIME` columns when you ask for `->date()`, not a simple `DATE` column like I thought.

Assumptions: tut, tut.